# Can you provide an example where a rational power irrational number is rational?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

There is very common example for rational power irrational is rational $2^{\log_2 3}$, is there any other example, that doesn't contain $\log$ term in power?

Comment: $1^\pi =1$, although it's a very sad example :)

Comment: Well, if $m,n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\},\ m\ne1$ and all the numbers are coprime, then

$$\left(\frac mn\right)^\alpha=\frac rs\iff \alpha=\log_{\frac mn}\frac rs=\frac{\ln r-\ln s}{\ln m-\ln n}$$ so I guess the answer is kinda "no" (I'm not an expert of number theory: it might be an oper problem whether natural logarithms of coprime integers $>1$ are algebraically independent).

Comment: (... and $\frac rs\ne\frac mn$, of course)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_theorem

Comment: It is known, from the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem][1], that if $a\in \mathbb{Q}-\{0,1\}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic, then $a^b$ is a transcendental number, hence irrational. So, the irrational numbers that you seek to this exponent, must be transcendental to make your example possible. The bad thing is, transcendental numbers are not that easy to work with...

  [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfondsTheorem.html

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

Here is an example where a rational power irrational number is rational: $1^\pi = 1$

This example does not contain a log term in power, as requested.